# Is it possible to create multi keys generator in Ehcache

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I use ehcache in my Spring web application for caching object from database (in DAO).
Like:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="mycache", keyGeneratorName = "MyKeyGenerator")
public List<Entity> getEntityByChannel(String channel);

@TriggersRemove(cacheName="mycache", keyGeneratorName = "MyKeyGenerator")
public void persiste(Entity entity);
```

The class MyKeyGenerator returned the key for cache, but is it possible to returned many keys?

For instance - return double keys key1 and key2 for one value. And remove caching by key1 or key2.

PS: Someone help me?